# Is VPN Service can Protect me from Govt Spy or Tracking?

Tags: vpn

Since couple days, I read one website, these days Govt, tracking all local users internet activity and found one solution, VPN technology can protect me from all type tracking? Is it right? if yes then recommend me right solution which I need to  use for my personal activity...

Comment: By using a VPN you switch all potential tracking from your ISP to your VPN.

Answer (score 3):

Using a VPN is like asking a friend from another city or country to post a letter for you. If you are scared about your post office opening the letter it's great, but you run the risk of having either your friend or their post office opening the letter, or both.
At some point the letter will have to go through the post to reach its recipient.

In other words, a VPN provider is just another Internet acces provider. Deciding to use a VPN is equivalent to deciding who you trust more, the VPN company or your home Internet provider.

Using a VPN only masks your IP address. You can still be tracked by the websites you browse, with tracking cookies, browser detection or behavioral analysis. And of course, if you log into websites (Google, Facebook, Stack Exchange...) with a user account, they'll identify you anyway, VPN or not.

---

If you are specifically worried about government spying, then you should be fine using a foreign VPN provider, on the condition that you trust the provider and the spies from the provider's own country to not send your data to your government.

Comment: But can you give me any specific name that offering good service, when I will buy any VPN service, what features I need to take in my mind?

Comment: Sorry, software/service recommendation is [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here. Also, "good service" is subjective and depends on your specific requirements. Finally, I don't know much about commercial VPN companies and as such I can't direct you to a suitable provider.

Comment: The features you need to consider when choosing your VPN, again, will vary depending on your use case. But honestly, all VPNs will brag about "maximizing your privacy", "protecting you online", etc. If security is your first concern, any commercial VPN service will do, provided you trust the provider. Cf my post.